# Multi line chart using d3 and json in a nvd3 structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a multi line chart using d3 and data in a json format. For some reason my code isn't working. I haven't been able to find out where I'm doing wrong. Have searched the web and read a lot of examples, to no avail. I've probably stared me blind on the code.

In the example, I'm only trying to draw two lines, but the number of lines are not known. So I can't hard code it. Does anyone have any tips on where I'm doing wrong?

Jsfiddle link to the code. http://jsfiddle.net/6qrcmsnj/3/

Here is also the code.

```
var w = 700;
var h = 600;
var pad = 80;

var time_format = d3.time.format("%I:%M:%S");

var gd = example_data(4);


var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(gd[0].data, function(d) { return d[0]; }))
    .range([pad, w - pad]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(gd[0].data, function(d) { return d[1]; })*2])
    .range([h - pad, pad]);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "chart")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(time_format);

var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
    .interpolate("linear");

// Just for a grey background.
canvas.append("rect")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "#E8E8E8");

// Add x-axis.
canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform","translate(0," + (h - pad) + ")")
    .call(xaxis)
    .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "rotate(-65)"
                });

// Add y-axis
canvas.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", 0)")
    .call(yaxis);

// Add line
canvas.selectAll("path")
    .data(gd)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", line(gd.data))
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1)
    .attr("fill", "none");

function example_data(val) {

    if (val == "4") {
        return [
            { "label" : "Data_1", "data" : [ [ 1404438592000, 21.09 ], [ 1404438593000, 10.85 ], [ 1404438594000, 15.74 ], [ 1404438595000, 20.86 ], [ 1404438596000, 10.83 ], [ 1404438597000, 8.92 ], [ 1404438598000, 23.68 ], [ 1404438599000, 20.68 ], [ 1404438600000, 14.68 ], [ 1404438601000, 4.65 ]] }, 
            { "label" : "Data_2", "data" : [ [ 1404438592000, 3.219 ], [ 1404438593000, 1.641 ], [ 1404438594000, 6.68 ], [ 1404438595000, 2.543 ], [ 1404438596000, 8.522 ], [ 1404438597000, 4.616 ], [ 1404438598000, 9.703 ], [ 1404438599000, 3.737 ], [ 1404438600000, 8.752 ], [ 1404438601000, 1.791 ]]}
        ];
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LarThoren method will certainly work but with `d3` we like to avoid explicit looping.  Your version misses two things:

```
canvas.selectAll(".series") //<-- don't selectAll with "path", there are other paths in the axis and you selection needs to be more specific
  .data(gd)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d){ //<-- gd is out of scope here, you need to use the accessor function
    return line(d.data);
  }) 
  .attr("class", "series")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("stroke-width", 1)
  .attr("fill", "none");
```

Full working code:

```js
var w = 700;
var h = 600;
var pad = 80;

var time_format = d3.time.format("%I:%M:%S");

var gd = example_data(4);
 
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
 .domain(d3.extent(gd[0].data, function(d) { return d[0]; }))
 .range([pad, w - pad]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
 .domain([0, d3.max(gd[0].data, function(d) { return d[1]; })*2])
 .range([h - pad, pad]);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(xScale)
 .orient("bottom")
 .tickFormat(time_format);

var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(yScale)
 .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
 .x(function(d) { return xScale(d[0]); })
 .y(function(d) { return yScale(d[1]); })
 .interpolate("linear");

// Just for a grey background.
canvas.append("rect")
 .attr("width", "100%")
 .attr("height", "100%")
 .attr("fill", "#E8E8E8");

// Add x-axis.
canvas.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform","translate(0," + (h - pad) + ")")
 .call(xaxis)
 .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
    });

// Add y-axis
canvas.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", 0)")
 .call(yaxis);

// Add line
canvas.selectAll(".series")
 .data(gd)
 .enter()
 .append("path")
 .attr("d", function(d){
     return line(d.data);
 })
 .attr("class", "series")
 .attr("stroke", "black")
 .attr("stroke-width", 1)
 .attr("fill", "none");

function example_data(val) {
 
 if (val == "4") {
  return [
   { "label" : "Data_1", "data" : [ [ 1404438592000, 21.09 ], [ 1404438593000, 10.85 ], [ 1404438594000, 15.74 ], [ 1404438595000, 20.86 ], [ 1404438596000, 10.83 ], [ 1404438597000, 8.92 ], [ 1404438598000, 23.68 ], [ 1404438599000, 20.68 ], [ 1404438600000, 14.68 ], [ 1404438601000, 4.65 ]] }, 
   { "label" : "Data_2", "data" : [ [ 1404438592000, 3.219 ], [ 1404438593000, 1.641 ], [ 1404438594000, 6.68 ], [ 1404438595000, 2.543 ], [ 1404438596000, 8.522 ], [ 1404438597000, 4.616 ], [ 1404438598000, 9.703 ], [ 1404438599000, 3.737 ], [ 1404438600000, 8.752 ], [ 1404438601000, 1.791 ]]}
  ];
 }   
}
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
 fill: none;
 stroke: black;
 shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The missing "function" part was just a typo. The original code has the full line in it. Not sure why my jsfiddle didn't.

The "selectAll" part did the trick. Finally working now. After hours of searching and reading, the solution was that easy. But I would probably not found out by my self. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I copied your jsfiddle to a stack snippet that can be viewed below. Looping through the data creating a line for each post.

```
for(var i = 0; i < gd.length; i++)
{
   canvas.append("path")
   .data([gd[i].data])
   .attr("d", line).attr("class", "line" + i);
}
```

```js
var w = 700;
var h = 600;
var pad = 80;

var time_format = d3.time.format("%I:%M:%S");

var gd = example_data(4);
var xScale = d3.time.scale()
  .domain(d3.extent(gd[0].data, function(d) {
    return d[0];
  }))
  .range([pad, w - pad]);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(gd[0].data, function(d) {
    return d[1];
  }) * 2])
  .range([h - pad, pad]);

var canvas = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "chart")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var xaxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xScale)
  .orient("bottom")
  .tickFormat(time_format);

var yaxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yScale)
  .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  })
  .interpolate("linear");

// Just for a grey background.
canvas.append("rect")
  .attr("width", "100%")
  .attr("height", "100%")
  .attr("fill", "#E8E8E8");

// Add x-axis.
canvas.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - pad) + ")")
  .call(xaxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".15em")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
  });

// Add y-axis
canvas.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + pad + ", 0)")
  .call(yaxis);

for (var i = 0; i < gd.length; i++) {

  // Add line
  canvas.append("path")
    .data([gd[i].data])
    .attr("d", line).attr("class", "line" + i);

}

function example_data(val) {

  if (val == "4") {
    return [{
      "label": "Data_1",
      "data": [
        [1404438592000, 21.09],
        [1404438593000, 10.85],
        [1404438594000, 15.74],
        [1404438595000, 20.86],
        [1404438596000, 10.83],
        [1404438597000, 8.92],
        [1404438598000, 23.68],
        [1404438599000, 20.68],
        [1404438600000, 14.68],
        [1404438601000, 4.65]
      ]
    }, {
      "label": "Data_2",
      "data": [
        [1404438592000, 3.219],
        [1404438593000, 1.641],
        [1404438594000, 6.68],
        [1404438595000, 2.543],
        [1404438596000, 8.522],
        [1404438597000, 4.616],
        [1404438598000, 9.703],
        [1404438599000, 3.737],
        [1404438600000, 8.752],
        [1404438601000, 1.791]
      ]
    }];
  }
}
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.line0 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
.line1 {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However the 

    canvas.selectAll("path")
        .data(gd)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("d", function(d) { return line(gd.data); } );

Does the same thing. Loops through the data creating a line for each.

Answer (score 1):

two changes

`.attr("d", line(gd.data))`

should be

`.attr("d", function (d) { return line(d.data) })`

and path first and then add axis. It should work. Basically selectAll('path') picking up path element from axis element.

Comment: That was actually just a typo, that ended up in my jsfiddle example. The original code has the whole function line. Thanks for making me aware of it.